# GameLoopThread in simple Android Game, how can i execute parallel thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-layout

I am developing an android game, i need some help regarding multi threading as i am considering it. I am attaching an image then i can explain what i need.[image]
The bird is moving perfectly in my game from left to right and right to left, also moving her feathers as two images used, but i run the code at some time which will start to give egg, forexample bird will fly for 4 minutes and after every 20 seconds it will drop the egg, now egg will move from top to bottom, and what i think, another game thread will be used, i have used GameLoopThread object for it and SurfaceHolder  holds the surface, 
I have used this code http://www.edu4java.com/androidgame/androidgame3.html
I can make the condition of 20 seconds to give egg, but i am confused how to make a thread for an egg which will move from top to bottom and on other-side bird will be keep moving.

Really thanks in advance.

Atif

Answer (score 2):

You need only one game thread, don't use two, it will make things just more complicated (you need to synchronize everything).

Usually a game thread does the following steps (and loops them forever):

- handles key/touch event
- performs the tick() (update of the sprites, states, etc)
- renders the screen

So, what you need to do, is have a list of sprites (bird, egg). You can keep them in an array. Then in tick(), you update the position of each of them.

The sprite list will be dynamic, at the beginning of course you will have only one sprite, the bird. When the egg is created, just add it to the sprite array, so from that point on it will be handled as well.

Comment: Can you send me some hint or link according to the code i used to develop this app, thanks.